# Is permute operation differentiable operation in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

For my project I am using [permute](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute) operation to change the index order of the e tensor in encoder path  but I am not sure if this is  differentiable operation? If it is not, Is there any way to change tensor shape before the convolution.

Comment: Permuting is differentiable, you can check it yourself. Have you tried it in your model? What was the result?

Comment: Model can't generalize  very well. So I want to be sure about that.

Comment: The rule of thumb is this: if an operation is *not* differentiable and you backprop through it, you will get an error for sure